# Argument list too long: '/bin/sh'

Tags: bash, python

I'm trying to invoke `tar`  command via `subprocess` call from Python.The challenge I have is there are a lot files that get passed on to `tar` which is causing the command to throw the error `Argument list too long: '/bin/sh'`

The command I'm running is below

```
subprocess.call(f"ulimit -s 999999999; tar -cz -f {output_file} {file_list}", cwd=source_dir, shell=True)
```

To try to overcome the error, I added `ulimit` which doesn't seem to help.

Please could I get help to solve this problem.

Comment: What operating system are you using? What does `ulimit -c unlimited` mean? I can't see how that would be relevant to the argument list limit. Where did you find that command? How are you building the file list? Can you pass an entire directory instead? Can you split the command into batches that append to the tar file?

Comment: This has probably been answered many times, but either tar from the parent directory and forget about individual files, of create a file list and pass that single file to tar with the -T switch.

Comment: Could you use directories instead of full path? If files are on same filesystem, just create a second hierarchy with hard link (so you will just occupy data for extra directories, not for files), and then you use tar on such tree.

Comment: Please do not multi-post across stacks (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70168398/argument-list-too-long-bin-sh)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using GNU `tar`, you can write the list of files you want in the tar archive to a text file and then use GNU tar's `-T` (aka `--files-from`) option.

From `man tar`:

> `-T`, `--files-from=FILE`
>
> Get names to extract or create from FILE.
>
> Unless specified otherwise, the FILE must contain a list
> of names separated by ASCII LF (i.e. one name per line).
> The names read are handled the same way as command line
> arguments.  They undergo quote removal and word splitting,
> and any string that starts with a `-` is handled as tar
> command line option.
>
> If this behavior is undesirable, it can be turned off
> using the `--verbatim-files-from` option.
>
> The `--null` option instructs tar that the names in FILE
> are separated by ASCII NUL character, instead of LF.  It
> is useful if the list is generated by `find`(1) `-print0`
> predicate.

Comment: Converted my comment to an [answer of its own](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/679623/106650); from the comment arose a "properer" way to do it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller yep, python's tarfile module is a good solution. +1

Comment: Thank you @cas. Helpful

Answer (score 6):

Passing file names as part of a giant string is **always** a bad idea (it breaks here instantly as soon as there's a single space in a single file name).

Instead, use the interfaces that allow you to supply a list of arguments as list; the `shell=True` option is a bad idea in nearly all cases, especially here (Say there's a file called `something; rm -rf ..` in there, this command will delete things you definitely don't want to have deleted...).

But as [cas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7696/cas) [said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/679621/106650), you really should instead be using your `tar`'s ability to read file names from a text file.

But even better: don't call an external `tar` at all. Just use the [Python `tarfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) module, that, yes, your Python comes with. Then you have none of these problems!

Extremely slightly adapting the shortest example from that module documentation above:

```
import tarfile
…
tar = tarfile.open(output_file, "w:gz")
for filename in files_in_an_actual_list:
    tar.add(filename)
tar.close()
```

Comment: Thank you Marcus. This is helpful